# How to stop splitting data in random forest regression

Tags: random-forest

I am currently working on writing a random forest regression code in Python and am struggling with it. My understanding is that, at each tree node, I select a feature (a column) to split the input X and label y into two groups. For example, with the dataset:

```
              |4|.    <== feature number
X = [[1, 4, 5, 2, 2], ==> goes to the Left node because 2 <= 5
     [3, 5, 1, 3, 2], ==> goes to the Left node because 3 <= 5
     [0, 2, 9, 6, 1], ==> goes to the Right node because     5 < 6
     [2, 2, 4, 3, 2], ==> goes to the Left node because 3 <= 5
     [1, 1, 4, 6, 2]] ==> goes to the Right node because     5 < 6
y = [1.0,
     1.4,
     2.9,
     1.9,
     2.2]
```

If I select the 4th column as the feature and 5 as the splitting condition, rows 0, 1, and 4 go to the left child node, while rows 2 and 3 go to the right child node. I then run multivariate linear regression within each child node. I repeat this process across all the columns, and choose the best feature and splitting condition that gives the minimum Residual Sum of Squares (RSS). My problem is determining when to stop this splitting process, as most of the cases there seems to be a point with the lowest RSS. Is it good to continue until the tree reaches its maximum depth?

I halt the data split when the combined RSS of the best two subgroups is below 90% of the original group's RSS.